# I want to create a speedometer style for my dashboard indicating the average response time for the month

Tags: tableau-api

How to plot a speedometer style graph in tableau that shows the average response time for the month.

For example, for bed tracking data, the response time meas a person that takes time to respond to the bed clean. SO I have the data for the whole month and what I need to do is to create a speedometer style indicating the average response time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you use a Bullet chart instead as the 'speedo' chart is not ideal, as it can be misleading.

That said, if you are determined and this is your only graph then have a look at this site
https://public.tableau.com/profile/adam.e.mccann#!/vizhome/Data16JediChartPresentation_Desktop3/SessionIntro
and view the Adam E McCann presentation from the "Gauge 4 How to" slide onwards

There is maths involved in doing this chart, but it is straight forward and quite satisfying to make Tableau do something that you truly created.
Good Luck.